# offsetParent temporarily disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, offset

RDC70 is the offset parent of RP70. At one point in the code, however, this is not the case. The following returns `null`:

```
console.log($('#RP70').get(0).offsetParent);
```

[Note: This is edited from the original post.]

Soon after, however, it gives:

```
<div id="RDC70" class="rdc" style="display: block;">
```

At both points, however, `console.log($('#RCD70'));` returns `[div#RCD70.rcd]`

So... I have two questions:
(1) What jQuery can I use to investigate RDC70 while the offsetParent relationship is broken?
(2) Why might this be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: When are you calling it? Document ready? load? More details are needed.

Comment: I can't really answer that, @epascarello, because its an AJAX script that loads once and then rolls on from there. Lots of stuff is hidden and displayed throughout, so maybe that may impact things. I can say, however, it's way after $.ready / load.

Comment: how is this code being called? Can you show more code?

Comment: Not really, @epascarello. It's fairly vast. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things could be happening. It seems most likely that the elements have not yet loaded into the DOM when you're calling the code that generates the "null" outputs.

From the Mozilla Developer Network:
offsetParent returns null when the element has style.display set to "none".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent

The offsetParent is not likely set to display: none though since it itself is returning null.

Comment: Apologies for errors in the initial observed results. They are correct now. Showing the known parent does not appear to correct the results, however.

Comment: This proved to be the crucial lead, @jholloman. Both the element and its parents were loaded, and the style.display for both was 'block'. However, a container div in which both reside had style.display set to 'none'. Thanks for the help. A shame I had to endure another -1 for asking a question that obviously displeased someone somewhere, but I appreciate your help :)